# Word VBA Error 4198 within an error handling loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

This problem is with MS Word VBA

I'm trying to handle a file open error, I'm assuming the file doesn't exist.

First time through the loop with a non existent file it works fine.

Second time through with the correct filename, it works fine.

However, second time through with non existent file I get

Run-time error '4198':

Command failed.

I need the code to loop until a file is successfully opened.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 Private Sub Document_Open()
      Dim BaseFilePath As String 
      Dim Filename As String 
      Dim SrcFileName As String 
      Dim LoopControl As String  
      BaseFilePath = "My Directory" 
      LoopControl = 0 
      Do While LoopControl = 0 
          Filename = InputBox("Enter Name of File", "FileName", "Enter File Name Here") 
          SrcFileName = BaseFilePath & Filename 
          MsgBox SrcFileName & LoopControl 'For diagnostics
          'Check Source File Exists    
          On Error GoTo errhandler     
          Documents.Open SrcFileName
          LoopControl = 1
          On Error GoTo 0 
errhandler:
          MsgBox LoopControl 'For diagnostics
          If LoopControl = 0 Then
              MsgBox "Booking Form Doesn't Exist" & vbNewLine & "Please Check Visit Date and School Name as per Booking Form Filename"
              On Error GoTo 0
          End If 
      Loop 
      MsgBox "File Exists" 
 End Sub
```

See explanation above

Comment: Why don't you use `Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)` to get the file from the user?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it much simpler to show the user a [familiar way to select the file](https://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/).

Also, please [always use `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html).

Here is an example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenBookingDoc()
    Dim rootFolder As String
    rootFolder = "C:\Temp\"
    
    Dim bookingFilename As String
    
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fDialog.InitialFileName = rootFolder
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Booking Files", "*.docx"
    
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
        '--- the user selected a valid file
        bookingFilename = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        Debug.Print "the user selected " & bookingFilename
        Documents.Open bookingFilename
    Else
        Debug.Print "the user selected Cancel"
    End If
    
End Sub
```